# System.Web.Http problem affecting communication

Tags: visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, system.net

It seems like there is a problem with the **"System.Net.Http"** dll.
I keep getting all kind of errors relating to it:
while trying to **restore nuget packages** (It seems like the framework can not connect to the nuget index:

```
Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json.
```

even while **trying to sign in to the microsoft account** through the Visual studio 2019 community:

```
we could not refresh the credentials for the account ...
Could not load file or assembly System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.2.0
```

It seems like a system problem. Where should I look\locate this dll in system level ?
PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a missing dll in the GAC:
In order to reach the GAC, type assembly as system variable in the run.
The missing dll should have been located in the System.Net.Http folder, in the GAC_MSIL (depend on the microsoft OS).
I took it from another source and located it there